# How many times there is a substring in a string [Java]

Tags: java, string, search, substring

I am trying to write a code in order to determine how many times there is the string s1 in the string s2.

This is the code I have written,but doesn't work:

```
package lab2_1;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "si";
        String s2 = "sir1 si cu sir2 fac un sir3";

        int count = 0;
        int ok=1;
        int i=1;
        for(i=0;i<=s2.length()-1;i++)
            if (s2.substring(i,i+s1.length()).equals(s1))
                count++;


        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Can you anyone please review my code and tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry about the ok=1 and i=1; I have removed them from the code.

Comment: Code review is off-topic for SO. For review, there is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If your code is not working, please describe your input, your expected output and your observed output.

Comment: @Turing85 Don't recommend CR, this is off-topic there.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Does the code print 4 and you expect 1?

Comment: Not working **HOW**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using the wrong end condition on your `for` loop. The highest index in `s2` that you attempt to access is `i + s1.length()`, so you need to make sure that's always at most `s2.length() - 1`.

Change your `for` loop to this:

```
for(i = 0; i + s1.length() < s2.length(); i++)
```

And it will work.

Comment: I was not able at that time :) .

Answer (score 1):

This is a little diffrent approach, but it should also work. You just split the string and check it's size -1:

```
String s1 = "si";
String s2 = "sir1 si cu sir2 fac un sir3";
String[] split = s2.split(s1);
System.out.println("number of substrings: " + (split.length - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would count how many times [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) returns a non-negative number:

```
int lastPos = -1;
int count = 0;
while (true) {
  lastPos = s2.indexOf(s1, lastPos + 1);
  if (lastPos < 0) break;
  ++count;
}
```

This is much more efficient than using `String.split` (or `String.substring`) because it doesn't construct any additional objects.

Comment: If I output numCcurrrences I get 0, for the strings in the question.

Comment: ...and that's why you give variables better names than `s1` and `s2`. Fixed.

Comment: Yuck. break statements in the middle of a while loop leave room for serious bugs later on down the road...

Answer (score 0):

fix of your soultion

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "si";
    String s2 = "sir1 si cu sir2 fac un sir3";

    int count = 0;
    int i=1;
    for(i=0;i<s2.length()-s1.length();i++) {
        if (s2.substring(i, i + s1.length()).equals(s1))
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}}
```

only for loop line is wrong

```
for(i=0;i<s2.length()-s1.length();i++)
```